# editing quoted text in Gmail iOS app

Tags: ios, gmail

The new Gmail iOS app (version 5.0.4) no longer allows me to edit quoted text in reply and forwarded messages. This is a serious limitation.

Is there a fix or a workaround, short of copying the entire quoted text, pasting it into Notes, editing it, and pasting the result back in Gmail?

(Despite the new look, version 5 seems to be a step in the wrong direction. The previous version worked just fine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed in version 5.0.7.